# What's the best way to make an entire div clickable, but keep the current style?

Tags: html, css, hyperlink

I have some text links inside divs and want to make the entire div clickable. When i do this i lose all style i added for the textlinks. What would be the best way to do this with just css?

All suggestions are welcome!

The column on the left i made the first link clickable by making the entire div clickable.
The 3 columns on the right are not clickable but have the style they should have.

Comment: And here is the Jsfiddle example: http://jsfiddle.net/Lookinggoodtoday/mb6xV/

Comment: you can use stretched-link class if you are using bootstrap. https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/helpers/stretched-link/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Whilst it will @MrRoss's answer will work in some browsers it is considered bad practice and is technically against W3C guidelines.

You can use javascript or you can try the below (I've found this to work on some of my sites):

```
<div>
    <a href="aLink.html" style="width:100%;height:100%;display:block">Your link</a>
</div>
```

This should make the div (up to the padding) behave like a link but should keep any styles you specify for the text in the link :)

Comment: This is the better answer due to the W3C compliance.

Comment: Thanks for this solution, i tested it and it works. It also saves another css rule for div. a.

Comment: Would it be possible and accepted by W3C guidelines to try and make the padding clickable? By changing width=100% into something like width=200px or width=120% ?

Comment: I don't know about that but if you're ok with it depending on javascript you could try

    <div onclick="window.location='aLink'">My Link Text</div>

which I believe should fire when you click anywhere in the div (including the padding).  Someone with better javascript knowledge can probably confirm if this is correct

Answer (score 1):

```
 <a href="adver.html"><div style="width:300px;height:200px;border:5pt double black;background-color:red;float:right;font-weight:bold;text-align:center;vertical-align:center"></div></a>
```

Just declare the anchor before the div! :)

Comment: So that's what i was doing wrong... Thank you for the solution!

Comment: Be warned that this is not W3C compliant and so is not guaranteed to work for all browsers, see my answer below for a W3C compliant solution :)

Comment: @Kvothe is right, as far as I know it works on all browser, just maybe not a mobile device(aside iPhone,, tested). If it is W3C valid their way, go with that. Sorry for the misdirect to bad practice.

Answer (score 0):

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/4dgaurav/3Cja3/)**

html

```
<a class="aFordiv" href="#">
    <div> I am a cliackable div </div>
</a>
```

css

```
div {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background: #aaa;
}

/* reset default styles for the anchor tag for each states */

.aFordiv, .aFordiv:visited, .aFordiv:link, .aFordiv:active, .aFordiv:hover, .aFordiv:focus {
    font-family:Arial;
    color:black;
    text-decoration:none;
    outline: 0;
}
```